# How to custom Image Picker like Facebook in React Native with Expo?

Tags: react-native

I want to customize Image Picker like Facebook does (image below) in React Native. But I cannot find any articles about this.

[image]

I have used expo-image-picker but it just shows Photo Library for picking images. But I just want to load all images from Photo Library and have my custom header (something like Facebook app).

Does anyone know how to customize Image Picker? Please give me an instruction. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check out libraries like [react-native-cameraroll](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll#getphotos) which could help with that. They allow you to read the images from cameraroll and you can decide what to do with it afterwards (eg. rendering into your custom UI)

If I'm not mistaken, expo-image-picker just pulls up the native system UI that handles image picking, just like the modal that shows up when you change an appleID profile picture in settings.